What happens to the fermion spin when I move around it in a full circle
I would like to understand the actual meaning of the description of a fermion as a spinor. I have a background in QFT and understand the calculations, but there is a leap to the actual experiment which I am not I able to visualise.
Suppose I have a fermion standing still (ignore the technical details, I just want to understand what in principle QFT tells us about the spin transformation).
I now measure the spin along the z-axis and find that it is up. Now I make a full circle around it, coming back to the initial position, without touching the particle.
Will I still measure a spin up along the z direction?
Is it because my rotation relative to the spring is actually two circle and not one? Doe it means that if I make only half rotation, to the antipodal point I will measure the sign difference?
If this is indeed the case, then I think that the whole "spin is getting a minus sign after a full rotation" is a bit misleading. I understand that when "rotating the fermion 360 degrees" rather then moving myself around it does flip its rotation, but this is less troubling for me.

My confusion arised from the fact that the phase of the state gets a minus sign, not thr expectations value of the spin.
Trivial, but I must throw some of the responsibility on people that visualising the fermion phase with a drawing of a ball, with a plus or minus sign, while talking on its spin.
